# Vue.js: How to access "this" in methods definition

Tags: vue.js

I define a plugin and use it like:

```
import * as d3 from "d3"
import Vue from "vue"


export default {
    install: function(){
        window.d3 = d3
        Vue.prototype.d3 = d3
    }
}
```

Then when I try to define a component methods using that plugin:

```
<script>
    export default {
        methods:{
            lineFunction: this.d3.line()
                             .x(function(d, i) { return i*10; }) 
                             .y(function(d) { return d*10; }) 
                             .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX)
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

It keeps giving me

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'line' of undefined"

**it seems this.d3 is not ready, I tried use d3 rather than this.d3, both are not working, thoughts?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lineFunction` has to actually be declared as a function, with parenthesis and braces:

```js
export default {
    methods: {
        lineFunction () {
             return this.d3.line()
                 .x((d, i) => i * 10) 
                 .y(d => d * 10) 
                 .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the return of this.d3.line()... is a function, I try to understand why there is no d3 plugin ready

Comment: @Kuan - You can't set it directly like that, because `this` is not in Vue's context without it actually being a function. If you want to set the function like that, you'll have to either import `d3` directly in this file, or do it in the `created` hook.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, although I do not understand why and how Vue treat it, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

`this`, in your case, points to the Vue instance, which can be used to accesss `props` (defined in 'props' block), `data` (defined 'data' block), `methods`, and some others. `d3` is not one of them.

To use d3, simply import it inside the `<scrip>` section:

```
<script>
    import * as d3 from "d3"
    export default {

        methods:{
            lineFunction: function() {
                 d3.line()
                             .x(function(d, i) { return i*10; }) 
                             .y(function(d) { return d*10; }) 
                             .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX)
                 }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but did u test your answer?